# How to correctly initialize, assign and use a dynamic Eigen matrix as a class member in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic, eigen

I have a class that has a dynamic Eigen matrix. I want to read a Matrix from a text file and assign it to the class matrix variable. What is the best way to do this? This is what I do at the moment

```
class MyFoo
{
    MyFoo();
    Eigen::MatrixXd mat;
    void setMatrix();
}

MyFoo::MyFoo(): mat(Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero())
{};

void MyFoo::setMatrix()
{
    mat = HelperLib::readMatFromTXTfile("someFileName");
}

// Eigen::MatrixXd HelperLib::readMatFromTXTfile(const string &fname);
```

My problems are this: first of all the initialization doesn't seem right. Secondly, using the = to assign the read matrix doesn't not seem too optimal either. Unfortunately there aren't many examples on the Eigen homepage for this or I am too much of a noob to understand them.

Comment: Since the right hand side of the assignment is an rvalue, the copy in the assignment will likely be elided via move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `MatrixXd` object is initialized to a `0x0` matrix, so no need to explicitly initialize it to an empty matrix. Moreover, the `Matrix<>::Zero()` static member is only for fixed size matrices. For a `MatrixXd` you need to specify its dimensions, typically `Zero(n,m)` is used to initialize a matrix to a `m x n` matrix filled with explicit zeros.

Regarding the assignment, CoryKramer already answered it.